# How to access other website session userid from one website in same solution in c#?

Tags: session, wcf-data-services, blogengine.net

I am developing WCF Service.In that I created one website and one blog(by using blogengine.net blog).In that I want to access Website session UserId from the blogengine.net blog. I added website reference to the blog. But I cant access the Website Session UserId from blog.Please anyone guide me how to access that.

Answer (score 0):

Your main website and blog website are two different websites?

Sound like you have an virtual application folder?

YourWebsite.com  and  YourWebsite.com/blog

Is that correct?

BE 2.5 and higher requires it own private application pool for it to work.

Because of this you have two unrelated application pools (app cache) and this is where the Session data is stored at.

So your main website:  MainWebsite.Com  can not access the session data from

Your Blog website:  MainWebsite.com/blog

and the other way around.

The only way to share data stored there is to store it some where or use JavaScript to post it to the other site.

What exactly are you trying to do?

If you can explain all of the steps you want to do it can help in maybe figuring out a better method to do this.